# dojo tree event on root nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

**I'm building dojo tree using the following code:
[image]

The tree is displayed as expected. The problem that I have is that the onClick event is only fired on leaf nodes. When I click on the root level node(I have several root level) it is just open showing child nodes.

How can I add "extra" onClick functionality to the root nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `openOnClick` set to true for your tree.  I think the API docs answer this as well as I possibly could.

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/Tree/openOnClick

That said, it looks like you'd be able to connect to `_onClick` instead and do whatever you want (that's the method responsible for calling `onClick` only when `openOnClick` is false, anyway).  Or, if you wanted to feel a little less guilty about accessing private members, `dojo.declare` yourself a subclass of `dijit.Tree`, extending `_onClick` to also fire another function you define as public.

Comment: I need to have actually both events enabled openOnClick and onClick. Can you please instruct how to set those variables. I have really minor experience with DOJO. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I already told you; in the simplest case, connect to _onClick.  In your current example, you'd change `"dojo/method"` to `"dojo/connect"` (so that you'll be connecting to method invocations, not clobbering the method), then change `event="onClick"` to `event="_onClick"`.

Comment: I just changed openOnClick to "false" and it is working. Thank you