# dojo how to override dijit class method

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I need to override onClick method in the Tree.js. Is there any common way to override dojo/dijit classes methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
dojo.connect(tree, 'onClick', function(item) {
    /** Your Action **/
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm a bit confused, since you were already doing this in the [last question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800261/dojo-tree-event-on-root-nodes).

You've got a few choices, depending on what you want to do.

### Clobbering method stubs

In the case of true stubs like `onClick`, it's potentially as easy as clobbering that method on your widget instance.

Programmatically:

```
var myWidget = new dijit.Tree({
    ...,
    onClick: function(item, node, evt) {
        /* handler code here */
    }
};
```

Or declaratively (this is exactly the same as what you were doing in your last question):

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Tree" ...>
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="item,node,evt">
        /* handler code here */
    </script>
</div>
```

### Connecting to method invocations

In other cases, perhaps you need to do something whenever a given method gets called, in which case you could use the widget's `connect` method (which is a nicer version of `dojo.connect` that will automatically clear itself when the widget is destroyed).  In that case you could do something like this:

Programmatically:

```
//execute the given function whenever myWidget's onClick method is called
myWidget.connect(myWidget, 'onClick', function(item, node, evt) {
    /* handler code here */
});
```

Declaratively, this can be done very similarly to the above, except instead of `type="dojo/method"`, make sure you use `type="dojo/connect"`

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Tree" ...>
    <script type="dojo/connect" event="onClick" args="item,node,evt">
        /* handler code here */
    </script>
</div>
```

Note that when you connect like this, your code will execute *after* the method whose invocation you are connecting to.  If you need to do something *before*, your best option is probably to `dojo.declare` your own extension to the widget.  If you need to go that far, I'll elaborate, but I think you'll likely be set with one of the above options.

### Edit #1: Connecting the dots (no pun intended...oh heck, yes it was)

Since it seems that my comment appended to my [answer to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800261/dojo-tree-event-on-root-nodes/4801040#4801040) was somehow not clear enough, here's a code block modifying the original code in that question based on the simple two steps *exactly* as I explained in that comment.  The only tiny wrinkle is that the arguments passed to `_onClick` are slightly different.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Tree" ...>
    <script type="dojo/connect" event="_onClick" args="node,evt">
        /* handler code here. In this case, item is accessible via node.item */
    </script>
</div>
```

This solution may feel a bit sub-optimal since it involves connecting to a method that's suggested to be private.  However, it's a way that should work regardless of whether `openOnClick` is true or not.  If you are certain you're going to have `openOnClick` set to `true`, you could potentially write a single function, then connect it to both `onClick` and `onOpen` instead (both get passed the item, then the node).

### Edit #2: Common functions, connecting programmatically

To answer your follow-up questions, I'd like to actually address them in reverse order - since if you are interested in connecting programmatically, it will actually make the other question easier to answer.

So first, to answer your `connect` question: you definitely don't want to be using `dojo.byId`, as that's not giving you the Tree widget, that's giving you some DOM node (probably the topmost) associated with the widget.  As a general rule, `dojo` methods don't know anything about `dijit` stuff.

What you do want to be doing, is what I suggested above.  Here it is applied as per the code you attempted.  Also note that `onClick` has a *capital* C - another general rule: widget events use camel case notation, as a way to distinguish them from plain DOM events which don't.

```
var mytree = dijit.byId("mytree");
mytree.connect(mytree, "onClick", function(item) {
    /* ... */
});
```

Now, to take that a step further and resolve your other inquiry, if you want to bind some common functionality to `onClick` and `onOpen` and `onClose`, you could define a function first, then connect it to both.  This is one of the many things that makes JavaScript awesome - the availability of functions as first-class objects that can be easily passed around.

```
function handleClick(item) {
    /* do stuff here.
    Inside this function you can assume 'this' is the tree,
    since connect will ensure it runs in-context.
    */
}
var mytree = dijit.byId("mytree");
mytree.connect(mytree, "onClick", handleClick);
mytree.connect(mytree, "onOpen", handleClick);
mytree.connect(mytree, "onClose", handleClick);
```

Now there's one important remaining question:  where should we *do* this?  The best place is likely inside a function passed to `dojo.ready` (or `dojo.addOnLoad`, same thing, `ready` was added as a synonym in 1.4) so that it will run only after:

- The DOM is parsed by the browser
- All `dojo.require`d modules have loaded
- If you set `parseOnLoad: true` in `djConfig`, all widgets defined in the document's HTML will already be instantiated

So, sometime after your `dojo.require`s, in script, you'd do this:

```
dojo.ready(function() {
    /* code from previous example goes here */
});
```

Give it a shot.

Also, if you're interested in a bit of reading, I've actually written about a couple of topics I touched on in this edit:

- [Of Dijits and DOM Nodes](http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/of-dijits-and-dom-nodes/)
- [`dojo.require`d Reading](http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/08/dojo-required-reading/)

Comment: The problem that i have that onClick even is not fired at all. I cannot catch it. If you look in the Tree code it says something like that: If node expandable expand it, else do something. I need to have if not expandable expand and do something. When openOnClick="true" and node is expandable I cannot catch onClick event. So far nothing that you suggested worked for me.

Comment: In that case, (1) you didn't really ask the question you're actually asking, and (2) I answered the question you *are* asking in my answer to your *other* question (which I linked at the top of this answer).  To repeat both answers, you should be able to use the connect approach given here to connect to the Tree's `_onClick` method to do what you want.

Comment: Since we already know what question I'm asking. Would you please just put some line of code in response. Considering that my code is: <div dojoType="dijit.Tree" id="mytree" model="continentModel"
 openOnClick="true">
 <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="item">
           console.debug("We here");
    </script></div>
</div> What exactly should I write? Sorry for making it not clear.

Comment: I've added a sample doing exactly what I said in the comment on the other answer - I'm really not sure what was so hard to follow...  But I'm still confused, since on that thread you said you changed `openOnClick` to `false` and that would also solve your problem.

Comment: First if you don't want to answer don't answer. Second I thought that it solve my problem because I could catch event by clicking on node and expand node by clicking on the "+" sign. But enevtually I need to have both functionalities. The reason I'm asking again and again because I cannot connect your answers in something I can use. I have 0 web experience and just two words answer "use _click" doesn't help. Again you don't have to answer.

Comment: I already did answer, see the "Edit" portion of the answer above. ;) Sorry for giving you a hard time, but please do realize that people answering questions can get equally frustrated when it feels like a decent explanation plus a simple connect-the-dots has been turned down in favor of just asking for the code to be handed out.  I see it happen more and more often, so I apologize for letting the frustration out here.

Comment: Now I saw the Edit portion it really helped. I create three separate callbacks: <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="item">
   console.debug("onCLick");
    </script>
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onOpen" args="item">
   console.debug("onOpen");
    </script>
 <script type="dojo/method" event="onClose" args="item">
   console.debug("onClose");
    </script></div> It is perform functionality I need. MY questiont can it all this logic combined in one call? Aslo when I'm trying to use dojo.connect(dojo.byId("mytree"), "onclick",... it doesnt work. Any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: I've added "Edit #2" in response to those questions; take a look.

Comment: Thank you. This is fantastic explanation. I have some further questions if you don't mind. In one case I see I can pass only one parameter to the function, other case two or three. How many there are ,and how I access there values. For example I want to know what even had happens or what are the values of my node. How do I access it? May be I should post it as another question?

Comment: That question is probably easy to answer, if I've interpreted the question correctly.  Have a look at the Event Summary section of the API doc page for Tree: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/Tree - it tells you what parameters get passed to each exposed event.  It's up to you whether you actually want/need to use all of them though.  If you do have additional broader questions, yes I'd suggest perhaps asking as a new question, as this "answer" has gotten kind of long-winded by now :P